# Rails query to return distinct resources based on associated resource

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct

I need to gather a users recent broadcast tags.

I have these models set up

```
class Broadcast < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :broadcast_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :broadcast_tags
end

class Tag < AR::Base
  has_many :broadcast_tags
  has_many :broadcasts, through: :broadcast_tags
end

class BT < AR::Base
  belongs_to :broadcast
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

I would like to find Tags from the users broadcasts in the last month

I figure I need to join broadcasts to tag  and then find all tags that are used in those broadcasts

```
Tag.joins(:broadcasts).where(
  broadcasts: { user_id: current_user.id, created_at: Time.current.all_month }
)
```

This returns individual tags multiple times if the user has used them in more than one recent broadcast. I would like to only receive distinct tags. Which of course works fine if I just call distinct.

```
Tag.joins(:broadcasts).where(
  broadcasts: { user_id: current_user.id,   created_at: Time.current.all_month }
).distinct
```

I also need to order these distinct tags by the order in which they are found in the broadcasts.

So if

- the last broadcast has tags 10, 9, 6, 1
- the next to last has tags 9, 2, 1

I would like the tags to be returned in this order

10, 9, 6, 1, 2

I've tried `.order('broadcasts.created_at DESC')` which complains `for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching and head scratching and documentation reading I realised I can do this

hopefully it helps someone else

```
Tag.joins(:broadcasts).where(
  broadcasts: { user_id: user.id, created_at: Time.current.all_month }
).group('tags.id, tags.name').order('max(broadcasts.created_at) DESC')
```